# Invoking base methods in classes

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm working on a game, and one of the things I want to do is to have a base class that defines an attribute damage, and uses a constructor to initiate that value. This is my base class

```
class Weapon(object):
def __init__(self, damage):
    self.damage = damage
```

This is the actual class that calls on Weapon for the game

```
class Crossbow(Weapon):
is_loaded = True
reloads = 5
def __init__(self, is_loaded, reloads):
    super(Crossbow, self).__init__()
    self.is_loaded = is_loaded
    self.reloads = reloads

def reload(self):
    print "You need to reload, before you can fire again"
    time.sleep(2)
    if reloads > 0:
        print "Reloading bow"
        time.sleep(2)
        reloads -= 1
        is_loaded = True
        print "Successfully reloaded bow"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "You now have",reloads,"arrow left"
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        print "You don't have any more arrows"
        time.sleep(2)
```

I was testing the reload function using:

```
c = Crossbow(Weapon)
for i in range(1,6):
    c.reload()
```

The reason I run the class method 6 times, is that I wanted to test the reload variable which counts how many times you reload. It subtracts each time it counts, and once it reaches zero, it doesn't let you reload, so 6 times would be able to test the full functionality. However, when I run that block of code, I get this error:

```
me.py", line 47, in <module>
c = Crossbow(Weapon)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I've used classes before, but I'm new to creating a base class and constructor and calling other classes off of that. If someone could help me understand my problem, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Don't try to declare defaults as class attributes. It's not an "optional nice thing to do" it's putting something there that shouldn't be there. In Python the correct way to create instance attributes is to just assign `self.attribute = ...`

Comment: Yeah, this is a common practice but usually a bad one.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a positional argument to your class's `__init__` method, that means you're committing to passing in the arguments each time you instantiate the class.  Because you've declared `is_loaded` and `reloads` as positional arguments to your `Crossbow` class's `__init__` method, you must provide them when instantiating.  In your testing code, you're providing the class `Weapon` as the value of your `__init__` call's first positional paramater, `is_loaded`.  This is, of course, wrong, but not a syntax error.  You're not providing any argument at all for `reloads`, and that is a syntax error.

You may wish to set default values for the arguments which will be used if not provided, eg:

```
def __init__(self, is_loaded=True, reloads=5):
    super(Crossbow, self).__init__(damage=5) # or whatever for damage
```

If you do that, you can instantiate without explicitly setting the values.

You could also set the default values to None and only override the class's values on a non-None value:

```
def __init__(self, is_loaded=None, reloads=None):
    super(Crossbow, self).__init__(damage=5)
    if is_loaded is not None:
        self.is_loaded = is_loaded
    if reloads is not None:
        self.reloads = reloads
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an instance of Crossbow with `c = Crossbow(initial_load_state, initial_reloads)`, not `c = Crossbow(Weapon)`. (Also, your superclass constructor call is missing a `damage` argument.)